# Form submit simulation - Javascript menu

Tags: javascript, forms, menu, user-input

I'd like to get contents of a website using JavaScript menu. I need to simulate clicks (or typing javascript:gotoPage("p10"); into a browser) on menu links to be able to move from one page to another.
The website uses a form activated by JS. It's probably not possible to go to another page by entering URL, because there are some hidden fields (something like hash- it's dependent on time and the page #). That's why I have to simulate a browser using user.

Basically the process will look like this:
     while (any_content) {
     file_get_contents();
     clickalink(); 
    }

Can cURL or JSON be used for this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PrototypeJS you could perhaps use the event.simulate library to simulate clicks on links.

https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/event.simulate.js

```
$('link_id').simulate('click');
```